# How to to do a index.php check for each IP in text file

Tags: python, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to make a script for each ip in my list txt with a connection checks whether the index exists and if it exist write to a txt file the ip with the relative check path

I have tryed with this

```
while line:
    print line
    import httplib
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection( x )
    conn.request("HEAD", "/index.php")
    r1 = conn.getresponse()
    print r1.reason

import logging
if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, filename="logfile", filemode="a+",
                    format="http://" + x + '/index.php' " " "%(message)s")
    logging.info( r1.reason )

    reload(logging)
```

ips.txt contains 3 ip

8.8.8.8

9.9.9.9

7.7.7.7

How i can check for each if if exist index.php

```
example: 8.8.8.8/index.php 
If exist write 8.8.8.8/index.php  to result.txt
if not exist go to second ip
```

Comment: please fix the indentation in your code

Comment: what is not working? Also if you are reading from a file don't use a while loop just iterate over the file object

Comment: how i read line by line ?

Comment: `with open(your_file) as f: for line in f:...` obviously needs to be indented also put your imports at the start not in the loop, you only need to import it once

Comment: thanks and how i can do a check of each ip

Comment: 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.8.9 If it have an index

Comment: you need to add a sample of your text file to your question

Comment: added sample of my text file content and what i want :)

Comment: @SemWilliamCersosimo, not 100 percent on what you want to do and presuming they are not the actual ips try the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not familiar with httplib but I imagine you need to catch a socket error:

```
import httplib
from socket import error

with open("in.txt") as f, open("out.txt","a") as out: # change to w if you want to overwrite each time
    for line in f:
        try:
            conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(line.rstrip())
            conn.request("HEAD", "/index.php")
            r1 = conn.getresponse()
            print(r1.reason)
            if r1.reason == "OK":
                out.write(line)
        except error as e:
            print(e)
```

Comment: If the host is not up i recive an error and script crash

Comment: what exception are you getting?

Comment: Perfect but he dont write to out txt file

Comment: and out.write(line) dont write to out.txt